Cannot find account in organization usage account as account admin
I cannot find the account in organization usage but the account is already created and enabled orgadmin
when i select the query, select * from snowflake.organization_usage.accounts where account = 'xxxx'; results 0.
when i check the accounts under admin, account is visible.

Organization_usage.accounts view has 24h latency. In Snowsight SHOW command is probably used. show ACCOUNTS HISTORY LIKE 'DATA_A%';

Use ACCOUNT_NAME column in the filter
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/organization-usage/accounts#columns
select * from snowflake.organization_usage.accounts where ACCOUNT_NAME = 'XXXX'; 
or
select * from snowflake.organization_usage.accounts where ACCOUNT_NAME ilike 'XXXX%'; 


even with the query account name is not visible in organization usage accounts.
ex. Account is DATA_A which is present in admin accounts but not in organization usage.
select * from snowflake.organization_usage.accounts where ACCOUNT_NAME = 'DATA_A'; 0 results found

Is SHOW ACCOUNTS HISTORY LIKE 'DATA_A%'; returning rows?

Yes. there is a history in the accounts

The earlier suggestion with snowflake.organization_usage.accounts should work.
select * from snowflake.organization_usage.accounts
where account_name = '<NAME>';




Glad, it worked for you

Thank you for responding to my question. Upon reading the documentation, it needs 24 hrs waiting time or latency after being made the account into orgadmin.
